# to crop a image by selecting part of imageusing ActionScript3.0 and Flex3.0

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex3

To crop the image into a selected size by drawing rectangle over it. It should be done in ActionScript 3.0  and Flex 3.0

warm rgds,

Comment: Thx Amargosh, I will try it out now and see.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `BitmapData.copyPixels()` for this.

```
//create a rectangle
var cropRect:Rectangle = new Rectangle(left, top, width, height);
//create new bitmap data - because BitmapData's width/height are read only
var bmpData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(cropRect.width, cropRect.height, true);
bmpData.copyPixels(image.bitmapData, cropRect, new Point(0, 0));
//assign the cropped bitmap data to the image.
image.bitmapData = bmpData;
```

`copyPixels()` [method](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#copyPixels())

```
public function copyPixels(sourceBitmapData:BitmapData, sourceRect:Rectangle, 
    destPoint:Point, alphaBitmapData:BitmapData = null, alphaPoint:Point = null, 
    mergeAlpha:Boolean = false):void
```

> Provides a fast routine to perform pixel manipulation between images with no stretching, rotation, or color effects. This method copies a rectangular area of a source image to a rectangular area of the same size at the destination point of the destination BitmapData object.